# Android App Multiple Views

Tags: java, android

This is one of the noobiest questions you will ever find, but in my Android app, I need to have a few different "screens"; one where you log in, and a view that represents a question (there will be multiple questions, so I need to make a view for each question and have it change to the next view when a next button is clicked. Let me explain with a flow chart:

User Opens App -> Login Screen -> User Logs In -> View changes to auto generated view for question 1 -> Next button clicked -> question 2 -> does all questions -> Final view that says you are done.

I have created two `xml` layout files, one called main and one called quiz (which represents a question).

I will elaborate on anything needed.

**UPDATE**

Here are my two activity classes:

```
package me.nrubin29.quiz.student;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);
        final EditText serverAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.serverAddress);
        final EditText secretNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secretNumber);
        final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String addr = serverAddress.getText().toString();
                String num = secretNumber.getText().toString();
                String n = name.getText().toString();

                if (addr.equals("") || num.equals("") || n.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You didn't fill in all the fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                new Connection().initConnection(Main.this, addr, num, n);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
package me.nrubin29.quiz.student;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class Quiz extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz);

        final RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        final RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        final RadioButton radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        final RadioButton radioButton4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);

        radioButton1.setText("Testing!");
    }
}
```

And here are my two XMLs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please enter the server address and secret number your teacher gives you."
            />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/serverAddress" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:phoneNumber="true"
            android:hint="Server Address"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/secretNumber" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:phoneNumber="true"
            android:hint="Secret Number"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:id="@+id/space1"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Please enter your name."
            android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:hint="Name"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:id="@+id/space"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Done"
            android:id="@+id/done" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Question"
            android:id="@+id/textView"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New RadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE!** And here's my newer Connection class:

```
package me.nrubin29.quiz.student;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import me.nrubin29.quiz.student.receivedQuiz.Quiz;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Connection {

    private Connection() { }

    private static Connection instance = new Connection();

    public static Connection getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private Quiz quiz;
    private Socket socket;
    private Thread reader;
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream;

    public void initConnection(final Activity activity, final String ip, final String port, final String name) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Starting connection to " + ip + ":" + Integer.parseInt(port), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    socket = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                    outputStream.writeObject(name);

                    quiz = new Quiz((String) inputStream.readObject());

                    Intent i = new Intent(activity, me.nrubin29.quiz.student.Quiz.class);
                    activity.startActivity(i);

                    reader = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            while (true) {
                                try {
                                    Object in = inputStream.readObject();
                                }
                                catch (final EOFException e) { activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } }); }
                                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    reader.start();
                }
                catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public Quiz getQuiz() {
        return this.quiz;
    }
}

As far as the Activity for Quiz, I guess I should make a constructor that takes the question and answers and sets the text of the radio buttons? Also, how exactly (code example would rock) would I create go about answering the question with the code above?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the login `Activity` just use whatever you `layout` you want with the `View`s needed (`Spinner`, `TextView`, `Button`, etc...).

If the question screens will all be the same then you can just use `Fragments` coupled with `ViewPager` if you want. This should work nicely for your needs. This will allow you to supply new data for each question but easily keep the same `layout`.

[VeiwPager Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

[ViewPager example](http://www.vogella.com/code/de.vogella.android.viewpager/src/de/vogella/android/viewpager/ViewPagerActivity.html) I haven't looked at it much but his tutorials are usually pretty good.

If `ViewPager` is more than you need/want right now, you can simply have one `View` for the question such as a `TextView` and change the text when the `Button` is clicked.

**Edit**

Change your `Intent` to use that `Context`

```
  Intent i = new Intent(activity, Quiz.class);
  activity.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: So if I use a `ViewPager`, I should generate every single `view` and put them all in an `array` and use that `array` with the VewPager?

Comment: No, you put the data in an `Array` then you can use the same `View`s and just update the data in each page

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to have the one `view` and update the view with the new text. How can I simply set the active view to `quiz.xml`? I can handle the button listener and text changing and stuff.

Comment: You don't want to be changing xml files within the same `Activity`. That just leads to more confusion and errors. What I was saying about that was if you are simply displaying a different question in the same `TextView` then you store your questions in an `ArrayList`, `Hashmap`, or whatever you want and just change the text of that `TextView`.

Comment: I need to have a connect screen, quiz screen, and done screen. I made the connect screen, and I made the quiz screen that changes the text based on the current question. I will make the done screen. What I need to know is how to switch the active screen from connect to quiz. Also, I believe I have the quiz screen in its own Activity class.

Comment: You start `Activities` using [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).
`Intent i = new Intent(ConnectActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);
startActivity(i);` And the quiz `Activity` should be in its own `Activity` class

Comment: After I receive the Quiz object from the InputStream, I do `Intent i = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), me.nrubin29.quiz.student.Quiz.class);
                    activity.startActivity(i);` but I don't think that works.

Comment: No, do as I showed in my previous comment using the `Activity` name you are currently in.

Comment: I am in a class called Connection which handles connecting to the server and sending/receiving data. In my main activity, when I initiate the connection, I pass the main activity in the method args (`public void initConnection(final Activity activity, final String ip, final String port, final String name) {`).

Comment: Pass the `Activity Context` then using `this` to your constructor and use that `Context` instead of `Application Context`

Comment: I am very new at this, so I don't quite understand. I have posted my latest code for the Connection class. Please tell me the exact line to change. Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Two things: 1. I still need an Activity to call `runOnUiThread()`. 2. Do I need to make the `Context c` variable or can I just use the `context` variable?

Comment: Using `Intent i = new Intent(activity, me.nrubin29.quiz.student.Quiz.class);
                    context.startActivity(i);` doesn't work. I get the `Connected!` `toast`, but nothing happens afterwards. Maybe there's another way to go about this?

Comment: See my edit. Use the `activity` variable but you will also need to add it to `startActivity()`. Sorry, its been a long day and I think I've confused myself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37976/discussion-between-pogostick29-and-codemagic)

Comment: @PogoStick29 Let me know if you need more help and we can continue in the chat

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this by having two different Activities  and each having different content views (XML Files).
The default Launcher activity will be your Login Screen with the login layout file.

The second activity should be having a view to handle questions. This can be done using your apt view groups like RelativeLAyout, LinearLayout, FrameLayout and so on. There are numberous examples on each in the internet. Just do a search for tutorials on each.

Final view (you are done) can be implemented in the same activity with a different view or just with a `AlertDialog`.